# How to add files to Visual Studio target filter but not target sources via CMake

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, cmake, qt5

I'm using CMake 3.5+ to manage my Qt5 project. As I'm developing with both, CLion and Visual Studio, I'd like to use the VS target filters.

As recommendet for CMake 3.5 and Qt5, I'm using `CMAKE_AUTOMOC=ON` and `CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR=ON`.

My files are organized in the following way

```
myLib
  impl
    bar.cpp
    bar_p.hpp
    foo.cpp
    foo_p.hpp
  bar.hpp
  foo.hpp
```

The CMake file for `myLib` looks like

```
add_library(myLib STATIC
            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/impl/bar.cpp
            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/impl/foo.cpp)
target_link_libraries(myLib
                      PUBLIC Qt5::Core)
```

The pattern for my source and header files is as follows:

`bar.hpp`:

```
#pragma once
#include <QtCore/QObject>

class BarPrivate;

class Bar : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  public:
    // the usual stuff
  private:
    QScopedPointer<BarPrivate> q_ptr;
    Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE(Bar)
};
```

`impl/bar_p.hpp`:

```
#include "bar.hpp"

class BarPrivate {
  Q_DISABLE_COPY(BarPrivate)
  public:
    // the usual stuff
  private:
    Bar* const q_ptr;
    Q_DECLARE_PUBLIC(Bar)
};
```

`impl/bar.cpp`:

```
#include "bar.hpp"
#include "impl/bar_p.hpp"

// definitions for BarPrivate
// definitions for Bar

#include "moc_bar.cpp"
```

That works fine on Unix (e.g. in CLion) and gives me clean and warning-free builds also with Visual Studio.

However, in VS, only the source files are displayed under the `myLib` target, while the header files are put under the *gather-all* filter *External Dependencies*.

I tried adding the header files to the target either directly with `add_library` or via `target_sources`. Unfortunately, this results in compiler warnings (VS) or compiler errors (GCC) due to multiple declarations of symbols from the Qt meta-object system (as generated in the moc files).

How can I get the header files out of the *External Dependencies* filter in Visual Studio while getting stable warning-free builds?

Comment: I use [`SOURCE_GROUP`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/source_group.html) to organise the files as I like.

Comment: Sounds strange since `.hpp` files given as source files are normally ignored: `set(CMAKE_CXX_IGNORE_EXTENSIONS inl;h;hpp;HPP;H;o;O;obj;OBJ;def;DEF;rc;RC)`. What do you get for `Item Type` of the `.hpp` files in VS? I would expect `C/C++ header`.

Comment: @DanMašek `source_group` is only applied to files added to a target. As the header files are not part of the target (as it would result in compiler errors), that command does nothing.

Comment: @Florian The `.hpp` files in _External Dependencies_ are of _File Type_ _C++ Header File_ and _Included in Project_ is _false_.

Comment: @Torbjörn I always have `.hpp` files in the list of sources passed to either `ADD_LIBRARY` or `ADD_EXECUTABLE`, and haven't seen a problem yet.

Comment: Ok. Found the issue. Omitting the `#include "moc_bar.cpp"` fixes the problem, as `CMAKE_AUTOMOC` creates a `myLib_automoc.cpp` files, which is automatically added to the target and includes the `moc_*.cpp` files, thus resulting in redeclaration of symbols.